# Как получить несколько самых больших значений из списка?

Tags: python

Например у меня есть список:

```
arr = [1, 200, 400, 2, 100]
```

Как я могу получить три самых больших значений из списка?

То есть, должно получиться:

```
[400, 200, 100]
```

Пробовал функцию `max()`, но она возвращает только самое максимальное значение - 400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [1, 200, 400, 2, 100]
print(sorted(arr, reverse=True)[:3])
```

Comment: можно и чуть покороче `print(sorted(arr)[:-4:-1])`

Answer (score 4):

Если у нас есть список размерности `list_len` и мы хотим найти `N` наибольших / наименьших элементов, то для случаев когда `N << list_len` (т.е. когда `N` значительно меньше `list_len`) разработчики Python рекомендуют использовать [heapq.nlargest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) / [heapq.nsmallest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

> `heapq.nlargest(n, iterable, key=None)` Return a list with the n
> largest elements from the dataset defined by iterable. key, if
> provided, specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract
> a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example,
> key=str.lower). Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key,
> reverse=True)[:n].
>
> The  latter two functions perform best for smaller values of n. For
> larger values, it is more efficient to use the `sorted()` function.
> Also, when `n==1`, it is more efficient to use the built-in `min()` and
> `max()` functions. If repeated usage of these functions is required,
> consider turning the iterable into an actual heap.

```
from heapq import nlargest

res = nlargest(3, arr)
```

результат:

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]: [400, 200, 100]
```

Comment: Наверное стоит уточнить, что рекомендуется для малых списков на выходе, а не на входе. У варианта с `sorted` сложность `O(m + n*log(n))`, а с `nlargest` – `O(n + m*log(n))`, где `n` - размер ввода, а `m` - вывода. Поэтому использование огромных списков на входе в контрасте с малым размером вывода приветствуется :)

Comment: @extrn, спасибо! действительно, ответ был совершенно по-дурацки сформулирован.  Попробовал исправить...)

Comment: я тоже неправильно оценил сложность `nlargest`, там скорее что-то вроде `O(m + (n - m)*log(m))`

Answer (score 2):

Ради интереса сравнил скорости этих сортировок на 100 000 элементах... И нашёл ещё более быстрый способ, кажется:

```
from heapq import nlargest
import random
import numpy as np

n = 100000
arr = list(range(n))
random.shuffle(arr)
arr_np = np.array(arr)

%timeit res_sorted = sorted(arr, reverse=True)[:3]
%timeit res_heapq = nlargest(3, arr)
%timeit res_np_sort = np.sort(arr_np)[-1:-4:-1]
%timeit res_np_part = -np.partition(-arr_np, 3)[:3]
```

Результат:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 41.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.47 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.25 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
```

Обычная сортировка понятно самая медленная - списки в питоне не очень быстрые, а тут приходится сортировать весь список.

`nlargest` отбирает элементы в 10 (!) раз быстрее. И это логично - ведь тут не нужно переставлять местами элементы или их индексы в огромном списке, а нужно только отобрать самые большие элементы в отдельный список.

Сортировка в `Numpy` работает в 2 раза медленнее, чем `nlargest`, но, учитывая, что она создаёт новый `numpy.array` того же размера, что и исходный, это, наверное, логично.

И, наконец, победитель - функция `Numpy.partition`, которая возвращает массив, в котором гарантированно отсортировано только заданное число элементов в начале массива. У неё нет сортировки по убыванию и приходится немного извращаться чтобы получить таковую, но работает она в итоге в 4 (!) раза быстрее, чем отбор максимальных элементов через `nlargest`. `Numpy` вообще очень сильно оптимизированная библиотека, я не удивлён.

Такие дела.